# Why does the lighting do not work?

Tags: rendering, node-editor, shaders, lighting

[image]

it worked before but I decided to turn up samples and turn on denoising and such because it had to much noise/ white pixels and then after that the render is so dark. Here is the blender file [image]

Comment: How strong is the sun lamp? Is there something in it’s way? (The position of sun lamps is irrelevant as they are treated as if they were infinitely far away)

Comment: please provide your blend file

Comment: no matter how strong the sun lamp is, it still stays the same whether its on 7 or 100000 @ZargulTheWizard

Comment: Pardon but how can I do that? @Chris

Comment: Go to this page https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: @Chris my file is 39.2mb I can not uplaod it :')

Comment: Try to make it smaller and seperate your problem

Comment: @Chris done! I just removed some of the objects

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but i think you clamped the light too much.

I got this:

[image]

if i increase your clamping (clamping direct and indirect light) from 0.03 to 0.2

[image]